# python format_spec syntax [[fill]align]

Tags: python

What does this ( [[fill]align]) syntax mean?

From the format specification mini language
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Does it mean if you have a fill then you must have an align?

I was trying -

```
In [71]: '{:{}{}}'.format('test','.','10')
Out[72]: 'test'
```

I think that has a fill(character) '.' and width ('10'). I used python 3.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you want to look the the examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatexamples).

The fill characters and the justification parameters go in as part of the string. For example

```
In [56]: '{:.<10}'.format('test')
Out[56]: 'test......'

In [57]: '{:.>10}'.format('test')
Out[57]: '......test'
```

If you want to dynamically generate the format string you could do something like this,

```
In [76]: '{:{}<{}}'.format('test','.','10')
Out[76]: 'test......'
```

Comment: You actually can nest replacement fields with `str.format`. That's not new with f-strings.

Comment: Adding to @user2357112: Your second example could be done as a single step with `'{:{}<{}}'.format('test', '.', 10)`. Each positional argument is used as the "thing to format" based on the position of the left brace, so the first left brace matches `test`, the second `.`, the third `10` (which can be an integer, it need not be a string).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a fill, you must have an align. The `.` in your test is not treated as a fill, because you are missing an align; instead, the `.10` is parsed as the `10` specifying a *precision* value. See the `[.precision]` in the [format spec syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For a string, a precision value of 10 will truncate the string to 10 characters:

```
>>> '{:{}{}}'.format('123456789012345','.','10')
'1234567890'
```

If you had an align, then the `.` would be treated as a fill:

```
>>> '{:{}>{}}'.format('test','.','10')
'......test'
```